# Delete all folders containing files which match pattern

Tags: find, directory, rm

I'm trying to delete all subdirectories of my current working directory which contain a rar file.

My first attempt: `find -name *.rar -exec rm -r {}/.. ';'` failed because that is not a valid directory. I tried using `dirname {}` for a more sensible command, but decided to just ask after almost deleting stuff I didn't mean to.

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a pair of statements.

First, get a list of directories to remove using

```
find -name *.rar -exec dirname {} ';' > toremove
```

Next, `cat toremove` to make sure it has the folders you want. Then, pass it to `rm -rf` using

```
sed 's/^/"/g' toremove | sed 's/$/"/g' | xargs rm -r
```

Last, `rm toremove`.

Comment: Excellent tip. This still doesn't quite work when the directory names contain spaces. I solved this by swapping the second line to `sed 's/^/"/g' toremove | sed 's/$/"/g' | xargs rm -r`

Comment: This will not work on files with spaces. Also will break if the current directory contains a `*.rar` file due to lack of quoting.

Comment: @MikeL: Thanks for the improvement; I replaced the second command with your version.

Comment: @MikeL This is good enough for you because Windows filenames can't contain `\"` or newlines, but in general, this method is unsafe. There's no convenient way to use `xargs` (except `xargs -0`) with arbitrary file names. It's usually better to [use `find -exec`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59890/delete-all-folders-containing-files-which-match-pattern/59913#59913).

Comment: @cpast `dirname` was a great idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

With zsh:

```
rm -rf **/*.rar(:h)
```

The suffix `:h` applies the [history expansion modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) `h` (“head”) which removes the basename of each match, keeping only the directory part.

Make sure to check that these are really the directories you want to delete! For example, move them to a temporary directory first:

```
mkdir DELETE
mv **/*.rar(:h) DELETE/
# check that you really want to delete everything in DELETE
rm -r DELETE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bash -c` to perform more advanced operations in and `-exec` for find. The problem with using a temp file and cat in combination with `xargs` is that it will break if a file contains a space, newline, or tab. The following should work:

```
find . -type f -name '*.rar' -exec bash -c 'rm -rf "${@%/*}"' -- {} +
```

Using `+` for find with "$@" will execute `rm` one time like with `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

Bash 4+ solution:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.rar; do rm -rf "${f%/*}"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
for dir in */; do             # iterate all subdirectories
    touch $dir"dummy.rar"     # create a "rar"-file...
    for file in $dir*.rar; do # ...so this won't break on zero such
        rm $file              # remove the dummy, and all archives
    done
done
```

Comment: OK, I read @cpast's answer and I see now that you want to remove the subdirectories, not the just the archives. My mistake! (But, isn't that a bit strange behavior?)