# Remove entire folder when grep find no files with a match inside the folder

Tags: shell, grep, directory, rm, xargs

I have thousands of folders with a single `html` file in each folder. I want to remove the entire folder if grep find no match to `example.com` in the `html` file.

I know how to remove the non matching file. For example like this:

```
grep -ZrLIi "example.com" "/dir/htmls/" | xargs -0 -I {} rm -f --
```

But instead of removing the file itself. How do I remove the entire folder the file is located in, including the other files in it?

Comment: `example.com` in the `html` file. I edited the post

Comment: Related - [Delete all folders containing files which match pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59890/100397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you have GNU coreutils, as you use non-POSIX flags in your grep:

```bash
grep -ZrLIiF "example.com" /dir/htmls | xargs -0 dirname -z | sort -zu | xargs -0 echo rm -rf
```

Remove the `echo` before `rm` if the output looks correct. I also added the `-F` option to do a literal match, not a regex one.

Comment: Have you tested this?  Looks like it only strips the filename from the last entry, instead of from every entry.  I think you meant to say `... | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c ...`

Comment: Oh, yeah, turns out that depends on shell. In Bash it strips it from every item, but in busybox ash and dash only from the last one. Thanks.

Comment: I modified the answer.

Comment: My testing was with bash 4.4 on Ubuntu 18. +1 for the revised solution though, and also for uniq-ing the output to avoid removing dirs twice.

Comment: Ubuntu's `/bin/sh` is `dash` by default, so that's what you used in your testing, probably. Because on Debian 9 with bash 4.4 I get: `bash -c 'set -- foo/bar one/two hello/world; printf %s\\n "${@%/*}"' \n foo \n one \n hello` (comments disallow newlines, so I replaced them with `\n`).

Comment: Can I stripe -F and everything will be safe to use? I want to search on multiple patterns at once

Comment: Sure. You can try with `echo rm -rf`, inspect the output, and see if command is safe to use.